# Redux state is returning html content in an array field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am doing a simple mern stack project using redux as state management tool. One of my state containing an array field to display all data from database displayed HTML content.

> Here is my reducers file for my redux which is todo.js.

```
const initialState={
        task:null,
        tasks:[],
        loading:true
    
    }
    export default function(state=initialState,action){
        const {type,payload}=action;
        switch(type){
            case ADD_TODO_SUCCESS:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading:false,
                task:payload
    
            }
            case ADDTODOS:
            return{
                ...state,
                tasks:payload,
                loading:false
                
            }
```

> My todo.js file inside actions folder is-

```
export const displaytodos=()=>async dispatch=>{
    
    try{
    const res=await axios.get('/');
    
        dispatch({

            type:ADDTODOS,
            payload:res.data
        })
        
    }catch(err){
        const errors=err.response.data.errors;
        if(errors){
        dispatch({
            type:ADD_TODO_FAIL
        })
    }}
};
```

> I have imported following file into my app.js

```
const Tasks = ({displaytodos,todo:{tasks,loading}}) => {
        useEffect(() => {
            displaytodos();
        
    }, [displaytodos])
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    )
}

Tasks.propTypes = {
    displaytodos:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    todo:PropTypes.object.isRequired,

}
const mapStateToProps=state=>({

    todo:state.todo
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{displaytodos}) ( Tasks)
```

> Redux store displayed the following todo state upon server start.
> [image]

> My backend code is -

```
app.get('/',async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        
        let task=await Tasks.find({});
        
        res.json(task);


    }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');

    }

    });
```

Comment: you need to give full path of API "/" that means it refer to your front-end path not back-end.

Comment: @Dhamala.Upendra I would not use the full path but instead use something like `/api` and set up a [proxy in the package.json](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)